# Snake in Haskell with Ncurses

Tags: haskell, snake-game, curses

I've created the Snake implementation in Haskell. User input and graphic is handled by the Ncurses library.

The goal of this question is to get the feedback on what can I improve to make it more Haskell idiomatic and readable. This is my first Haskell application bigger than simple Hello World examples, so I believe the code has many flaws and can be greatly improved.

The code is located in one file:

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Data.Time.Clock.POSIX
import System.Random
import UI.NCurses

currentTime :: IO Integer
currentTime = fmap round $ fmap (* 1000) getPOSIXTime

width :: Integer
width = 40

height :: Integer
height = 20

start = Vector 4 4

end = Vector ((x start) + width) ((y start) + height)

main :: IO ()
main =
  runCurses $ do
    setEcho False
    setCursorMode CursorInvisible
    w <- defaultWindow
    t <- liftIO $ currentTime
    g <- liftIO $ getStdGen
    loop w $ initial t g

initial t g =
  InGame
  { delta = 0
  , before = t
  , snake = [start]
  , velocity = Vector 0 0
  , direction = ToRight
  , generator = g
  , meal = randomMealPosition g
  , points = 0
  , delay = 100
  }

randomMealPosition g = Vector (position x) (position y)
  where
    position f = rand (f start) (f end)
    rand from to = (mod . toInteger . fst . next) g (to - from) + from

type Time = Integer

type Position = Integer

data Vector =
  Vector Position
         Position
  deriving (Eq)

x (Vector x _) = x

y (Vector _ y) = y

data State
  = InGame { delta :: Time
           , before :: Time
           , snake :: [Vector]
           , velocity :: Vector
           , direction :: Direction
           , generator :: StdGen
           , meal :: Vector
           , points :: Int
           , delay :: Time }
  | Lost

data Direction
  = ToLeft
  | ToRight
  | ToUp
  | ToDown

loop :: Window -> State -> Curses ()
loop w Lost = do
  first <- newColorID ColorRed ColorBlack 5
  second <- newColorID ColorGreen ColorBlack 6
  updateWindow w $ do
    setColor first
    moveCursor 16 16
    drawString "you've lost xD"
    setColor second
    moveCursor 24 24
    drawString "Press q to quit.."
  render
  ev <- getEvent w Nothing
  case ev of
    Just ev' ->
      if (ev' == EventCharacter 'q')
        then return ()
        else loop w Lost
loop w state = do
  now <- liftIO $ currentTime
  frameColor <- newColorID ColorRed ColorBlack 1
  snakeColor <- newColorID ColorBlue ColorBlack 2
  updateScreen frameColor snakeColor
  if (delta state > delay state)
    then loop w $ nextFrame now
    else do
      ev <- getEvent w $ Just 0
      case ev of
        Nothing -> loop w $ updateTime now
        Just (EventSpecialKey KeyLeftArrow) ->
          loop w $ (updateTime now) {direction = ToLeft}
        Just (EventSpecialKey KeyRightArrow) ->
          loop w $ (updateTime now) {direction = ToRight}
        Just (EventSpecialKey KeyDownArrow) ->
          loop w $ (updateTime now) {direction = ToDown}
        Just (EventSpecialKey KeyUpArrow) ->
          loop w $ (updateTime now) {direction = ToUp}
        Just ev' ->
          if (ev' == EventCharacter 'q')
            then return ()
            else loop w $ updateTime now
  where
    nextFrame :: Time -> State
    nextFrame now =
      if (hitsWall || hitsItself)
        then Lost
        else let updated = resetTimer now
             in if (eatsMeal)
                  then updated
                       { snake = newHead : snake state
                       , meal = randomMealPosition nextGenerator
                       , generator = nextGenerator
                       , points = points state + 1
                       , delay = delay state - 3
                       }
                  else updated {snake = move $ snake state}
    updateVelocity :: Direction -> Vector
    updateVelocity ToLeft = turn (Vector (-1) 0) $ velocity state
    updateVelocity ToRight = turn (Vector (1) 0) $ velocity state
    updateVelocity ToUp = turn (Vector 0 (-1)) $ velocity state
    updateVelocity ToDown = turn (Vector 0 (1)) $ velocity state
    turn :: Vector -> Vector -> Vector
    turn (Vector 0 dy) (Vector x y) =
      if (y /= 0)
        then Vector x y
        else Vector 0 dy
    turn (Vector dx 0) (Vector x y) =
      if (x /= 0)
        then Vector x y
        else Vector dx 0
    move snake = init $ newHead : snake
    hitsWall =
      let x' = x newHead
          y' = y newHead
      in x' > x end || x' < x start || y' > y end || y' < y start
    hitsItself = any (newHead ==) $ tail $ snake state
    eatsMeal = head (snake state) == (meal state)
    nextGenerator = (snd . next) $ generator state
    resetTimer now = state {delta = 0, before = now}
    newHead =
      updatePosition (head (snake state)) $ updateVelocity $ direction state
    updatePosition (Vector x y) (Vector dx dy) = Vector (x + dx) (y + dy)
    updateTime now =
      state {delta = delta state + (now - before state), before = now}
    updateScreen frameColor snakeColor = do
      updateWindow w $ do
        clear
        setColor frameColor
        moveCursor (y start - 2) (scale (x start))
        drawString $ "Score: " ++ (show $ points state)
        drawFrame start end
        setColor snakeColor
        draw glyphStipple $ meal state
        mapM drawSnakePart $ snake state
      render
    drawSnakePart = draw glyphStipple
    draw glyph (Vector x y) = do
      moveCursor y $ scale x
      drawGlyph glyph
      moveCursor y $ scale x + 1
      drawGlyph glyph
    drawFrame (Vector sx sy) (Vector ex ey) = do
      mapM_ drawBlock $ zip [sx - 1 .. ex + 1] $ repeat (sy - 1)
      mapM_ drawBlock $ zip [sx - 1 .. ex + 1] $ repeat (ey + 1)
      mapM_ drawBlock $ zip (repeat (sx - 1)) [sy - 1 .. ey + 1]
      mapM_ drawBlock $ zip (repeat (ex + 1)) [sy - 1 .. ey + 1]
      where
        drawBlock :: (Position, Position) -> Update ()
        drawBlock (x, y) = do
          moveCursor y $ scale x
          drawGlyph glyphStipple
          moveCursor y $ scale x + 1
          drawGlyph glyphStipple
scale x = 2 * x
```

Comment: Do you have a working project on gitlab you can provide a link to?

Comment: Yes: https://github.com/pchmielowski/Snake
I hope it works - I haven't touched it since two years ;)